# NodeJS wait until mySQL query is completed

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, asynchronous

I trying to pass a object from the controller to the view. Because I want to my model separate my query's from the controller I'm loading a JS object (model).

My model looks as follows:

```
function MyDatabase(req) {
  this._request = req;
  this._connection = null;

  this.init();
};


MyDatabase.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    this._request.getConnection( function(err, con) {
      if(err) return false;
      return this._connection = con;
    }.bind(this));
  },

  getFromTable: function(table) {
    this._connection.query('SELECT * FROM '+ table +';', function(err, result) {
      if(err) 
        return false;
      else if( !result )
        return {error: 'Error bij het ophalen van foto\'s'};
      else
        return result;
    }.bind(this));
  }
};

module.exports = MyDatabase;
```

But I can't figure out how to wait until this query is completed in my controller. I've found the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#retry) module and tried multiple function like waterfall and parallel, but none of them worked for me (or I didn't use it as supposed to).

My controller currently looks as seen below:

```
var myDatabase = require('../dbmodel');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var db = new myDatabase(req);

  async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
      var db = new myDatabase(req);
      var photos = db.getFromTable('photos');

      callback(null, photos);
    }
  ], function(p) {
    res.locals.photos = p;
    res.render('photos');
  } );
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I do understand that NodeJS works async and doesn't wait for any function to be completed. But there must be a way this is possible. What am I doing wrong, or what do I misunderstand?

Thanks in advanced! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getFromTable` method should accept a callback that will process the result of its execution.

```
// Accept a callback as a parameter
getFromTable: function(table, callback) {
  this._connection.query('SELECT * FROM '+ table +';', function(err, result) {
    if(err) 
      // execute the callback for a null result and an error.
      callback(err, null);
    else if( !result )
      callback(new Error('Error bij het ophalen van foto\'s'),null);
    else
      // execute the callback on the result
      callback(null, result);
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

The method can now be used in this manner:

```
// This is the callback to be passed into the method.
function processResult(err, result) {
  console.log(result);
}
db.getFromTable('photos', processResult);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! One little sidenote: In the else statement you pass `null` as the first parameter. When logging `result` in `processResult()` it returns `null` because the second parameter contains the `result`.

Comment: Thank you! That was a huge error on my part. I'll update the answer now.